# Datadog skip ingestion of Spring actuator health endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, datadog

I was trying to configure my application to not report my health endpoint in datadog APM./ I checked the documentation here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/ignoring_apm_resources/?tab=kuberneteshelm&code-lang=java

And tried adding the config in my helm deployment.yaml file:

```
            - name: DD_APM_IGNORE_RESOURCES
              value: GET /actuator/health
```

This had no effect. Traces were still showing up in datadog. The method and path are correct. I changed the value a few times with different combinations (tried a few regex options). No go.

The I tried the `DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT` environment variable, trying to ignore `http.route:/actuator/health`. Also without success.

I even ran the agent and application locally to see if there was anything to do with the environment, but the configs were not applied.

What are more options to try in this scenario?

This is the span detail:
[image: Span detail]

Comment: Having a very similar problem....The docs indicate you should use "GET /actuator/health"  ...I did the same thing on a project and its not working, as well.

Comment: Indeed, the string mentioned in the docs don't work. Let me know if you have progress in this, because I ran out of ideas

Comment: Will do! I had to take a break. I'll be jumping back on it later this week.

Comment: Followed [Advanced Log Collection Configuration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=helm#global-processing-rules_) today for setting up global processing rules- this stopped ingesting the logs on the Logs view in Datadog.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by Helm 'deployment.yaml', do you mean the 'values.yaml' file? I followed the documentation and here is what is working for me:

`datadog-values.yaml`:

```yaml
datadog:
  apiKey: XYZ-replace-me
  site: datadoghq.eu
  kubelet:
    tlsVerify: false
  apm:
    portEnabled: true
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
agents:
  containers:
    traceAgent:
      env:
        - name: DD_APM_IGNORE_RESOURCES
          value: GET /actuator/health
```

I install DataDog with Helm like this: `helm install dd -f datadog-values.yaml datadog/datadog`

Once everything is up and running, I see traces when I call my endpoints but the probes' traces do not appear.

Comment: This is on the agent level, I am trying to to on application level.

Comment: But this env is for the agent, not for your app. Have you tried this: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/ignoring_apm_resources/?tab=kuberneteshelm&code-lang=java#tracer-configuration-options ? Apart from this solution, I don't think there is any other way, at least not according to the docs. I don't think there is a way to do it declaratively, without writing code.

Comment: I Tried indeed but I am not really sure what to put in the value. The example uses the controller name with a specific syntax but I never found anything similar on my traces page

Comment: For my app, a Spring Boot application using the standard healthchecks, so exactly what you are doing, the resource name is "GET /actuator/health".

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in [Advanced Log Collectiojn](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=helm#global-processing-rules) and the logs are being filtered.

In my case, we are deploying to Kubenetes via a helm chart. So I updated my values file to have the following:

```
datadog:
   env:
     - name: DD_LOGS_CONFIG_PROCESSING_RULES
       value: "[{ \"type\": \"exclude_at_match\", \"name\": \"exclude health checks\", \"pattern\": \"((H|h)ealth[z]?)|((R|r)eadiness)\" }]"
```

It looks like the resource is still showing in the Service Catalog.

Comment: Log lines I was able to filter out too. How about APM traces, this is the problem I am facing.